# weight parameter elimination in neural network

Tags: neural-networks, regularization

I am a little new to neural network. I have two questions:
1. Can we use neural network in the small $n$ large $p$ situation?
2. Any regularization methods designed for parameter elimination? (Shrink some $\omega$ to 0). For example to add $L_1$ regularizer as Lasso? I know some methods for avoiding over-fitting, (weight decay, early stopping, ect.) but none of them shrink parameters to 0.

Answer (score 2):

you could iteratively reweight the parameters estimated by the $L_1$ regularization. 
Also what I do, is to apply the $L_1$ Lasso with a relatively large weighting $\lambda$ and then to remove all the parameters, which are at zero.  Then, ordinary ridge regression with a very small $\lambda$ can be applied efficiently, so you dont have drifts between the estimated and the "target" values due to regularization.

See

- [Generalized cross validation](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~wahba/ftp1/oldie/golub.heath.wahba.pdf) for obtaining $\lambda$,
- [Reweighting of lasso](http://inside.mines.edu/~mwakin/papers/rwl1-july2008.pdf)
- [Sparse Redundant Representations](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-1-4419-7010-7), somewhere in the chapter for shrinking algorithms. M. Elad calls the refitting with LSQ "projection".

Comment: Yes. But your answer seems to apply for linear regression. My question is for artificial neural network.

Comment: Well, these are very related problems. Consider the linear regression of type $y_j=\sum_i^N \varphi(x_i, x_j)\alpha_i$ where $\alpha_i$ are your parameters (weights in terms of ANN). In the case of ANN, you have the problem above multiple times, which leads to "deep learning".